# Listview is appearing behind top widgets when scaffold background colour is low shaded

Tags: flutter

I have noticed one issue while applying low shade colors to scaffold,

I have a Column that contains few widgets and expanded Listview,

while scrolling the listview upside, it is shown behind the top widgets of column

I have attached an image,

is there any solution to stop this behaviour of listview

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Balance Card'),),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(child: Text('History Card'),),
                ),
              ),


              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return ListTile(
                        tileColor: Colors.white,
                        title: Text(index.toString()),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),

        ),
      );
    }
```

Image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue.shade50,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Balance Card'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('History Card'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  tileColor: Colors.white,
                  title: Text(index.toString()),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

I guess you want a look like this.Can you check?